# How to integrate ibm watson chatbot with slack , using only OAuth access token

Tags: token, chatbot, ibm-watson, slack

When I was trying to connect my IBM Watson chatbot to slack, I noticed that slack has optimized their App options for connection and integration, where they generate only 'Bot User OAuth Access Token'. 
But IBM Watson slack integration process still asking in the second step: both: OAuth access token and User OAuth Access Token.
I tried to use the same token but doesn't work, I get my chatbot app on my slack workspace but no interaction.

My question is: how can I integrate my IBM Watson to slack with this new changes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a different system to Watson? I had a Bot powered by it but jumped shipped when it became difficult to use OAuth.

Comment: Check my answer you won't need to change IBM Watson service, it works

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it works ;)
 I tried to redo it again by understanding the new process, guess what? I find that slack has added again the 'OAuth access token'=> but if you keep following the IBM Watson slack integration steps you will keep facing problems (since it's not updated yet).
Here the steps I had followed:
1) Go to slack and create your app(https://api.slack.com/start)=> click [start Here] => at the bottom of page click [create a slack app] 
2) You will be redirected to *Building Apps for Slack* page.=> click [Bot] widget.
3) Click [review scope to add]=> in the second section_ Scopes_ fill out:
*Bot Token Scopes with :(app_mentions: read, chat:write, im:read ,im: write).
*User Token Scopes with:(im:read, im:write)
4)In same page go to the top f page and click [install App to workspace]=> click [Allow]
5)Then you'll be redirected to *OAuth Tokens & Redirect URLs* page, copy the 'OAuth Access Token' and 'Bot User OAuth Access Token'=> go to IBM WATSON SLACK INTEGRATION STEP2 and fill it=> you will need also to fill *verification token* by copy it from slack >basic information> App Credentials section > Verification Token.
6)Follow steps 3 and 4 as mentioned in IBM WATSON SLACK INTEGRATION.

And OPPPAAA you have your bot app in your slack space work in app menu ^__^.

P.S In 6) you may receive in the top of slack page notification ( reinstall .....), just do by clicking in the notification or  you will face PB in your app test.